# Style sheet positioning relative to menu load

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm doing some design work for a hotel website and noticed that the nav intermittently didn't load - I didn't build this site - but as i'm working on it i thought i'd fix for them - looking at the code the nav css was beneath the javascripts in the head - so I moved it to the top - seems to work in chrome/firefox/safari on my imac - but as I dont understand what the JS is actually doing in the page I'm paranoid It may effect functionality in other browsers!?

Probably just paranoia - but thought i'd check to ease my mind as I dont know if there was a reason that it was in this way in the first place - or simply bad coding!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascripts being included are standard jquery functions and should not have any impact as a result of the css being moved higher up.

As the load time of a file cannot be guaranteed, generally, I doubt any serious JS library would have issues with the order in which css was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Well, most people use Windows, so I'd suggest trying to get a [Wine port for MAC](http://www.davidbaumgold.com/tutorials/wine-mac/) running and install Firefox, Chrome, Opera and MSIE under it.

As for myself (Win 7, Chrome, FF, MSIE, Opera - newest versions), it looks ok.

Comment: if any of our answers helped you and are likely to help other people in the future, too, it would be nice to give us a +1 vote, so the question + answer will stand out to people searching for similar answers

Comment: sorry Zathrus - I dont have enough reputation to do that yet apparantley!

Comment: sure thing, glad to be of help :)